# How to resize a userform to fixed to a fixed height during when the form is running?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform with the following size dimentions:
Height = 140
Is't possible to resize the height of the userform to something like 280 with a click of a button?
Here is my code which doesn't produce expected results:

```
With me
If .Height <=140 then
    .Height = 280
Elseif .Height >=280 then
    .Height = 140
End if
End with
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With Me
        If .Height <= 140 Then
            .Height = 280
        ElseIf .Height > 140 Then
            .Height = 140
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```